# Sharepoint 2010. 'xsd is not defined' Error when trying to save edited list item or create new! IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In internet explorer 9 i have error when trying to save list item.

Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.

Before that i have javascript error inside some sharepoint files. This error says really nothing.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Namespace prefix 'xsd' is not defined.    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToXmlQualifiedName(String value, Boolean decodeName)
```

Comment: Has this page been modified in Designer by chance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the SharePoint client-side code, possibly as a result of changes to support branding. I have also seen it when trying to save a page I have edited. Your choices are:

1) Set your browser to use IE8 standards - you can do this by using F12 to get the IE developer tools panel and setting Document Mode to IE8 standards in the developer tools menu/ribbon thing.

2) Add the meta tag:  to your master page. This will force the browser to use IE8 Standards.

There is a little more detail in my [blog article](http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=namespace-prefix-xsd-is-not-defined).

Comment: We have had this same issue when trying to add support for some components of HTML5 and CSS3. This is exceptionally unfortunate as we want to use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` but apparently cannot. So much for "full support" of IE9.

Comment: IE 11 fails no matter what, but Chrome 34 works fine (though it adds the user twice).

Comment: there is actually a fix for this. see http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27251/hotfix-for-problem-with-sharepoint-peopleeditor-in-ie-9/34150

Answer (score 0):

This was problem with people pick up field! In IE9 if "compatibility view" not set on localhost we will have such error.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, and thus making my SharePoint Site very bland I change back from IE=9 to..

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```