# IE=edge Error Editing Lists

Tags: 2010, edit-form, browser-compatibility

So i recently switched my master pages to:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
```

from the former

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

In order to support the latest JavaScript for some new site additions.

The problem is... Since making the change I noticed that my old lists will now throw an error when trying to save an edit. The error is:

> Error: An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: f624e4aa-2b16-447d-83e5-84f8cb169e00

Any idea what is causing this issue?

I can no longer save edits to my old lists.

Comment: Can you get access to the ULS logs?  If you can, you can look up the error via the Correlation ID and see exactly what errors got logged.

Comment: Thanks! That allowed me to find a similar problem to my own. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22054/sharepoint-2010-xsd-is-not-defined-error-when-trying-to-save-edited-list-item

Answer (score 1):

Edge mode is not supported with SharePoint 2010... only 2013

> Internet Explorer 11 edge mode is not supported. Add sites to the
>   Compatibility View list to make some features work.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc263526(v=office.14).aspx

Try adding the site to Compatibility view and check what features are working.

Comment: So far no luck. If I'm in IE9 or 10 mode the Save button doesn't even function. IE11 mode of course throws the same error as using edge. Not using an IE browser is not an option as its 95% used by all my clients.